# How to iteratively replace a char in a string?

Tags: python

This should be a really simple problem, but I am stuck. I want to **iteratively replace each character in the string "PEPTIDE" with "A"** to result in: "AEPTIDE", "PAPTIDE", "PEATIDE", etc.

I know that strings are immutable in python, so I first convert the string to a list, then set a counter from 0 to len(str) and then replace the ith char with "A" and join the string back together. For some reason my code is not iteratively replacing A's, but rather just adding A's at each position:

```
pepSeq = list("PEPTIDE")
x = range(len(pepSeq))
for i in x:
    pepSeq2 = pepSeq
    pepSeq2[i] = 'A'
    print("".join(pepSeq2))
```

Result:
AEPTIDE
AAPTIDE
AAATIDE
AAAAIDE
AAAAADE
AAAAAAE
AAAAAAA

Any suggestions? It seems that the problem is occuring with my attempt to make a new variable pepSeq2 in an attempt to avoid replacing all chars in pepSeq with A.

Comment: You're not copying the list, you're just making a new reference to it.

Comment: try `pepSeq2 = pepSeq[:]` to make a copy of the list instead of a reference to it

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest and most Pythonic way is using splices** -- combining the part of the original string up to the character that needs replacing, the replacement character, and the rest of the string like so:

```py
s = "PEPTIDE"
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[:i] + "A" + s[i+1:])
```

or using list-comprehension

```py
s = "PEPTIDE"
variants = [s[:i] + "A" + s[i+1:] for i in range(len(s))]
```

---

Now let's compare the speed of the solutions here, in case the asker wanted to run this on a longer string. `by_splice` is mine, `by_copy` is what the asker tried to do, `by_enum` is what @smci and @Samwise suggested.

```py
def by_splice():
  s = "PEPTIDE" * 1000
  return [s[:i] + "A" + s[i+1:] for i in range(len(s))]

def by_copy():
  variants = []
  s = list("PEPTIDE" * 1000)
  for i in range(len(s)):
    ss = s[:]
    ss[i] = 'A'
    variants.append("".join(ss))
  return variants

def by_enum():
  s = "PEPTIDE" * 1000
  return [''.join([(c,'A')[j==i] for (j,c) in enumerate(s)]) for i in range(len(s))]


%time _ = by_splice()
%time _ = by_copy()
%time _ = by_enum()
```

```
CPU times: user 21.5 ms, sys: 15 ms, total: 36.6 ms
Wall time: 36.5 ms
CPU times: user 530 ms, sys: 27.4 ms, total: 557 ms
Wall time: 558 ms
CPU times: user 6.72 s, sys: 48.4 ms, total: 6.77 s
Wall time: 6.79 s
```

My solution (by splice) is the **fastest**, while the copy-based solution is **~15× slower**, and the enum-based solution is **~150× slower**.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to avoid this problem is to build a new list each time:

```
>>> for i in range(len("PEPTIDE")):
...     print(''.join("A" if i == j else c for j, c in enumerate("PEPTIDE")))
...
AEPTIDE
PAPTIDE
PEATIDE
PEPAIDE
PEPTADE
PEPTIAE
PEPTIDA
```

Comment: This solution is O(n^2) => takes seconds even on just a `len(s)==1000` inputs

Comment: good thing "PEPTIDE" only has 7 letters!  (If you know the size of the input will never change, all solutions are effectively O(1).)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make copy the entire list repeatedly. All that's necessary it to save and restore one character each iteration.

Here's what I mean:

```
pepSeq = list("PEPTIDE")

for i in range(len(pepSeq)):
    saved, pepSeq[i] = pepSeq[i], 'A'
    print("".join(pepSeq))
    pepSeq[i] = saved
```

Output:

```
AEPTIDE
PAPTIDE
PEATIDE
PEPAIDE
PEPTADE
PEPTIAE
PEPTIDA
```

Answer (score 0):

**One-liner nested list-comprehension** way of doing it:

```
[''.join([(c,'A')[j==i] for (j,c) in enumerate(s)]) for i in range(len(s))]

['AEPTIDE', 'PAPTIDE', 'PEATIDE', 'PEPAIDE', 'PEPTADE', 'PEPTIAE', 'PEPTIDA']
```

How does this work?

- generating the variations with a list-comprehension string-join `''.join([...])` is more Pythonic than iteratively overwriting the i'th element.
- the outer list-comprehension sweeps `i` over every possible letter-index: `i in range(len(s))`
- the inner list-comprehension iterates over the string...
- ...using `for (j,c) in enumerate(s)` as the Pythonic idiom to generate both each character `c` and its index `j`
- at each index we either select `c` or `'A'`, using the expression `j==i` as a numeric (0/1) index. This relies on boolean True/False being implicitly converted to integer 0/1.

Also here's the old-school **iterative-construct** way, which is less elegant and idiomatic but possibly more efficient:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    sout = s[:] # Make a copy
    sout[i] = 'A'
    print(sout)
```

Comment: `[s[:i] + "A" + s[i+1:] for i in range(len(s))]`, why over-complicate things?

Comment: @JanPokorný: because that only solves this specific case, but the nested list-comprehension shows you how to solve an entire class of problems (e.g. what if you had to substitute 2 distinct letters)

Comment: You could repeat the splice to replace multiple characters, and it still would be simpler and faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
pepSeq = list("PEPTIDE")

for i in range(len(pepSeq)):
    a = pepSeq[i]
    pepSeq[i] = "A"
    print("".join(pepSeq),end = ' ')
    pepSeq[i] = a
```

The OUTPUT is : AEPTIDE PAPTIDE PEATIDE PEPAIDE PEPTADE PEPTIAE PEPTIDA